# Даунгрейд с Python 3.6 на python 2.7, не могу понять как исправить эту ошибку и не очень понимаю структуру кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-2.7, атрибуты

Программа ругается на несуществующий атрибут, который походу создаётся в классе NetworkStatusDocument в списке ITEM вот так ItemObject(RouterObject, out_name='routers') , но по всей видимости, этот способ в Python 2.7 не поддерживается, хотел бы спросить как эт переписать

```
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\torpy\prog.py", line 4, in <module>
      tor = TorClient()
    ￼ File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\torpy\client.py", line 32, in __init__
      self._consensus = consensus or TorConsensus()#
    ￼ File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\torpy\consesus.py", line 144, in __init__
      self.renew()
    ￼ File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\torpy\utils.py", line 75, in newfn
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
    ￼ File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\torpy\consesus.py", line 171, in renew
      new_doc.link_consensus(self)
    ￼ File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\torpy\documents\network_status.py", line 371, in link_consensus
      for router in self.routers:

    AttributeError: NetworkStatusDocument instance has no attribute 'routers'
```

Вот кусочек модуля

```
class NetworkStatusDocument(TorDocument):
    DOCUMENT_NAME = 'network_status'

    # "network-status-version" SP version NL
    # [At start, exactly once.]
    # network-status-version 3
    START_ITEM = ItemInt('network-status-version')

    ITEMS = [
        # "vote-status" SP type NL
        # [Exactly once.]
        # vote-status consensus
        Item('vote-status'),
        # "consensus-method" SP Integer NL
        # [At most once for consensuses; does not occur in votes.]
        # [No extra arguments]
        # consensus-method 28
        ItemInt('consensus-method'),
        # "valid-after" SP YYYY-MM-DD SP HH:MM:SS NL
        # [Exactly once.]
        # valid-after 2019-07-20 21:00:00
        ItemDate('valid-after'),
        # "fresh-until" SP YYYY-MM-DD SP HH:MM:SS NL
        # [Exactly once.]
        # fresh-until 2019-07-20 22:00:00
        ItemDate('fresh-until'),
        # "valid-until" SP YYYY-MM-DD SP HH:MM:SS NL
        # [Exactly once.]
        # valid-until 2019-07-21 00:00:00
        ItemDate('valid-until'),
        # "voting-delay" SP VoteSeconds SP DistSeconds NL
        # [Exactly once.]
        # voting-delay 300 300
        Item('voting-delay'),
        # "client-versions" SP VersionList NL
        # [At most once.]
        # client-versions 0.2.9.16,0.2.9.17,0.3.5.7,0.3.5.8,0.4.0.5,0.4.0.6,0.4.1.2-alpha,0.4.1.3-alpha,0.4.1.4-rc
        Item('client-versions'),
        # "server-versions" SP VersionList NL
        # [At most once.]
        # server-versions 0.2.9.15,0.2.9.16,0.2.9.17,0.3.5.8,0.4.0.5,0.4.0.6,0.4.1.2-alpha,0.4.1.3-alpha,0.4.1.4-rc
        Item('server-versions'),
        # "package" SP PackageName SP Version SP URL SP DIGESTS NL
        # [Any number of times.]
        # Included in consensuses only for method 19 and later.
        # "known-flags" SP FlagList NL
        # [Exactly once.]
        # known-flags Authority BadExit Exit Fast Guard HSDir NoEdConsensus Running Stable StaleDesc V2Dir Valid
        Item('known-flags'),
        # "recommended-client-protocols" SP Entries NL
        # [At most once.]
        # recommended-client-protocols Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=1 HSDir=1 HSIntro=3 HSRend=1 Link=4 ...
        Item('recommended-client-protocols'),
        # "recommended-relay-protocols" SP Entries NL
        # [At most once.]
        # recommended-relay-protocols Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=1 HSDir=1 HSIntro=3 HSRend=1 Link=4 ...
        Item('recommended-relay-protocols'),
        # "required-client-protocols" SP Entries NL
        # [At most once.]
        # required-client-protocols Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=1 HSDir=1 HSIntro=3 HSRend=1 Link=4 ...`
        Item('required-client-protocols'),
        # "required-relay-protocols" SP Entries NL
        # [At most once.]
        # required-relay-protocols Cons=1 Desc=1 DirCache=1 HSDir=1 HSIntro=3 HSRend=1 Link=3-4 ...
        Item('required-relay-protocols'),
        # "params" SP [Parameters] NL
        # [At most once]
        # params CircuitPriorityHalflifeMsec=30000 DoSCircuitCreationEnabled=1 DoSConnectionEnabled=1 ...
        Item('params'),
        # "shared-rand-previous-value" SP NumReveals SP Value NL
        # [At most once]
        # shared-rand-previous-value 9 ybFb42KVOFmJR/EMtjPJNJiTBDyiI0eefmebenN9EY0=
        Item('shared-rand-previous-value'),
        # "shared-rand-current-value" SP NumReveals SP Value NL
        # [At most once]
        # shared-rand-current-value 9 p4+CMGa6M7EhDqGNpofcJ2MeQ7f7qdF8QslK+AOnrQg=
        Item('shared-rand-current-value'),
        ItemObject(DirSourceObject, out_name='voters'),
        ItemObject(RouterObject, out_name='routers'),#Создание атрибута
        # "directory-signature" [SP Algorithm] SP identity SP signing-key-digest
        #         NL Signature
        ItemSignature('directory-signature'),
    ]

    def __init__(self, raw_string):
        TorDocument.__init__(
            self,
            raw_string,
            digests_names=['sha1', 'sha256'],
            digest_start='network-status-version',
            digest_end='directory-signature ',
        )

    def link_consensus(self, consensus):
        for router in self.routers:             #Здесь проблема
            router._consensus = consensus
```

Создаётся ItemObject

```
class ItemObject(Item):
    def __init__(self, object_cls, out_name):
        Item.__init__(self,'', parse_func=None, out_name=out_name, as_list=True)
        self.object_cls = object_cls
```

А здесь суперкласс Item от которого наследуется ItemObject

```
class Item:
    def __init__(
        self,
        keyword,
        parse_func=ItemParsers.store_string,
        parse_args=None,
        out_name=None,
        type=ItemType.ExactlyOnce,
        as_list=False,
    ):
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.parse_func = parse_func
        self.parse_args = parse_args or []
        self.out_name = out_name or keyword.replace('-', '_')
        self.type = type
        self.as_list = as_list
```